# Will Xeon and i7 both work in the same motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility

I notice that both Xeon and i7 CPUs use sockets such as the LGA 2011.

Does this mean that either type of CPU will work in a motherboard with this kind of socket or does the motherboard need to be designed specifically for Xeon or Core processors (eg i9/i7/i5)?

Comment: Note that the names Xeon and i7 do not uniquely identify the CPUs. They are marketing terms that describe where they fit in Intel's product line at the time they were released. There have been Xeon's and i7s that used various different sockets, and there have been i7s that used the same socket, but couldn't use the same motherboard because they needed different chipsets.

Answer (score 1):

Every motherboard has a compatibility list, which list exactly what it's capable of using.  Look at it and match the processor to the board.  There's no guarantees that anything not on the list will work, even if it's the same socket.

Comment: I know that. The question is whether it is possible for Xeon and i7 CPUs to both use the same socket or is that impossible?

Comment: Check out https://pcpartpicker.com/list/Kpt4QV.  That currently has an i7 CPU.  If you replace it with a Xeon, the compatibility checker still says it's good to go.  https://pcpartpicker.com/products/cpu/?compatible_with=4jdqqs  This is a link to the compatability list of that mobo, which includes i7's as well as Xeons.

Comment: Guarantee of compatibility of listed items is not a guarantee of non-compatibility of non-listed items.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is the architecture of the chip dies itself. i7 and xeon do differ. they do not differ much, but they do.

the chip/processors have "special features" each.
and those specialities most likely will cause incompatibility.

you want to know it for sure, there's no ther way than trying it out yourself ynd then please share your expirience with us.